# I am developing an application using Reactjs, nodejs. How can i connect two different databases(mysql and couchbase) dynamically

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, couchbase

I am developing an application using reactjs and couchbase DB, how can i connect couchbase server and mysql so that i can connect them dynamically for CURD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at juggling-db project here at https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb

Answer (score 0):

If its React with both SQL and NoSQL, GraphQL is a good option. http://graphql.org/